# Lower bound for the maximum of independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,\dots, X_N$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables, I wonder how to obtain

$$\mathbb E(\max_{i\le N} X_i)\ge c\sqrt{\log N}.$$

To begin with, $$\mathbb E(\max_{i\le N} X_i)=\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(\max_{i\le N}X_i>t)dt-\int_{-\infty}^{0} \mathbb P(\max_{i\le N}X_i<t)dt \\
=\int_0^\infty  [1-\Phi(t)^n] dt-\int_{-\infty}^{0} \Phi(t)^n dt$$

where $\Phi(t):=\mathbb P(X<t)$, for a standard normal $X$. I don't know how to continue from here. Any approach will be appreciated!

Comment: http://www.gautamkamath.com/writings/gaussian_max.pdf

Comment: @GabrielRomon thanks a lot for the reference!